# How to redirect user to specific page in laravel 5.2 default register controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect the user to an introduction page after successful registration. But because the controller I used is the default for Laravel, I need to know how to customize the controller to fit my need.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect()->view('users/register_success_intro');

}
```

I used the code above but it doesn't work, I think its because of the return type. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: `return view('users.register_success_intro');` if you are redirecting to a view

Comment: you dont redirect it you just render the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AuthController.php`, you can define property `$redirectPath` or `$redirectTo`, you can either variable you want to use, they both work.

```
class AuthController extends AuthBaseController
{
    protected $redirectPath = '/home';
    protected $redirectTo= '/home';

    ...
```

You can verify the default code for redirection here `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers.php`

Answer (score 0):

inside `app/Http/Controller/Auth/AuthController.php`

```
  protected $redirectTo = '/welcome';
```

There is this protected $redirectTo change the welcome as accordingly your routes

Answer (score 0):

```
 return view('users.register_success_intro'));
```